# C# web api convert model class json to cipher text

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, cryptography, json.net

I am developing a mobile backend api application which is written in c# mvc4 web api.
My sample api method is given below

```
public IEnumerable<Contents> Get()
{
    var contents = contentService.GetAllContentsForApi();
    return contents;
}
```

"Contents" is my model class and i am returning that class which will be sent as json.

The sample json is as follows

```
{
    ContentId:1030,
    Title:"Hai iam a developer"
}
```

So my question is that can i have a method which will convert this model class to cipher text of json as follows

```
dfghfHG#$%GHT^%H^&HG&^**H
```

which can be decrypted at the mobile side as

```
{
    ContentId:1030,
    Title:"Hai iam a developer"
}
```

Comment: if you're doing the `encryption`, you know what to `decrypt` and how.For example convert it to a `base64` string, and the back.

Comment: i am just using return contents; statement.So how can i convert it or where should i convert it?

Comment: **how can i convert it** - there are a lot of ways. Look for `Encoding` class. **where should i convert it** - if you want to receive the encrypted data at your client, do it in your server.

Comment: @Amit Kumar thanks for your valuable comments i will look into it .

Comment: Why not just use HTTPS?

Comment: @Brian Rogers Thanks for your comment.My question is that is it 100% secure if i am just using HTTPS.

Comment: Yes, HTTPS will keep your data secure during transmission between server and client.  (That is the whole point of HTTPS, after all.)  If that is your goal, then you do not need to implement another layer of encryption over that.